# How to append a character at the end of a specific line in a loop?

Tags: bash

I want to read line numbers from a file and according to that insert characters in another file. This is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

character=:
line_number=1
sed $line_number's/$/ '$character'/' <readme >readme_new
line_number=3
sed $line_number's/$/ '$character'/' <readme_new >readme_newer
```

I would like to do that in a loop now.

Comment: Do what in a loop? Generate two new files, one where the first line gains a space and a colon and another where that same change is made to line 1, and also line 3? So just looping twice and making two files?

Comment: First, you *don't* want to call `sed` once for each line; that is grossly inefficient. There may be some cases where you can make some simple decisions within `sed` itself (I'm far from a `sed` expert; I'd rate myself "barely competent"), but this sounds like a job for an `awk` script instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
$: c='!'
$: sed "s#\$# s/\$/ $c/#" fibs >script
$: sed -i "$(<script)" infile
```

> Broken out -

A file of line numbers:

```
$: cat fibs
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
```

a file to be edited:

```
$: cat infile
  1 a
  2 b
  3 c
  4 d
  5 e
  6 f
  7 g
  8 h
  9 i
 10 j
 11 k
 12 l
 13 m
 14 n
 15 o
 16 p
 17 q
 18 r
 19 s
 20 t
 21 u
 22 v
 23 q
 24 x
 25 y
 26 z
```

3 steps -- first set your `c`haracter variable if you're using one.

```
$: c='!'
```

Then make a script from the line number file -

```
$: sed "s#\$# s/\$/ $c/#" fibs >script
```

which creates:

```
$: cat script
1 s/$/ !/
2 s/$/ !/
3 s/$/ !/
5 s/$/ !/
8 s/$/ !/
13 s/$/ !/
21 s/$/ !/
```

It's a simple `sed` to add a `sed` substitution command for each line number, and sends the resulting script to a file. A few tricks here include using double-quotes to allow the character embedding, and #'s to allow the replacement text to include /'s without creating leaning-toothpick syndrome from all the backslash quoting.

Then run it against your input -

```
$: sed -i "$(<script)" infile
```

Which does the work. That pulls the script file contents in for `sed` to use, generating:

```
  1 a !
  2 b !
  3 c !
  4 d
  5 e !
  6 f
  7 g
  8 h !
  9 i
 10 j
 11 k
 12 l
 13 m !
 14 n
 15 o
 16 p
 17 q
 18 r
 19 s
 20 t
 21 u !
 22 v
 23 q
 24 x
 25 y
 26 z
```

Let me know if you want to tweak it.

Comment: Ye, that's pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help. Thanks for the accept. ;)

Comment: Even though this works perfectly for the case I described, is there a way to append several characters to one line? Assuming I have a file like the following (the letters are all in a separate line):

`a
d
d
;
;
;
;`

And I want to have it like this (now all the characters are appended to the line where d is):

`a
d
d;;;;`